# Indexing a numpy array with another array containing out of bounds values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following data array:

```
d=np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
```

and another indexing array:

```
i=np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
```

What is a good way of indexing `d` with `i` (`d[i]`) so that instead of index out of bounds error for `6`, I would get:

```
np.array([10, 12, 13])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use `i[i < d.size]]` to get the elements that are less than the length of `d`:

```
print(d[i[i < d.size]])
[10 12 13]
```

Comment: Directly using the mask would also work: `d[i<d.size]`.

Comment: @Divakarm thanks,  that is a bit nicer but that would give 10,11,12 no or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Divakar, no worries, d.size is still nicer than len

Comment: I like that, nice and clean.

Comment: @And, it is the best I have to offer, there may well be better ways but I don't know them!

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to cleanup `i` before using it:

```
In [150]: d[i[i<d.shape[0]]]
Out[150]: array([10, 12, 13])
```

`np.take` has several `modes` for dealing with out of bounds indices, but 'ignore' is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the hints about take. I found it after posting the question, but indeed there is no "ignore". Padraic Cunningham was first with the main idea though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
valid_indices = i[(i >= 0) & (i < len(d))]
selected_items = d[valid_indices]
```

NumPy doesn't seem to provide an error-handling mode that skips invalid indices, probably because skipping them doesn't make much sense when the result array is multidimensional. Instead, just select the elements of `i` in the valid range and index with those elements.